# Group By is sorting the resultsets which I don't want...?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I am using following SQL Query:

```
SELECT `comment`.`id` AS `comment_id` , count( `comment_likes`.`comment_id` ) AS `number_of_likes`
FROM `comment`
LEFT JOIN `comment_likes` ON `comment`.`id` = `comment_likes`.`comment_id`
WHERE `comment`.`id`
IN ( 10, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 9 )
GROUP BY `comment`.`id`
```

Here the result of the query is coming as:

```
comment_id  number_of_likes
2           0
3           1
5           0
7           0
8           0
9           0
10          0
```

Which I don't want...? I want the same ordering given where condition i.e. **WHERE `comment`.`id`
    IN ( 10, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 9 )**.

So I want the result to be like:

```
comment_id  number_of_likes
10          0
5           0
7           0
8           0
3           1
2           0
9           0
```

Can anyone help me...?

Thanks In Advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add explicit `ORDER BY`. A function that can be helpful is [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(comment.id, 10, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `FIELD()` of MySQL in order to achieve your desired results

```
SELECT `comment`.`id` AS `comment_id` , 
        count( `comment_likes`.`comment_id` ) AS `number_of_likes`
FROM `comment` LEFT JOIN `comment_likes` ON 
       `comment`.`id` = `comment_likes`.`comment_id`
WHERE `comment`.`id`
IN ( 10, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 9 )
GROUP BY `comment`.`id`
ORDER BY FIELD(comment.id, 10, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 9)
```